# Error while Uninstall Crowdstrike from Remote computer using Powershell Script

Tags: powershell, server

This script was running well but suddenly not working. I can see that PS starts the CsUninstallTool.exe and exiting quickly.

```
$computerList = Get-Content "C:\\TCrowdStrike-Master\\ServersToCheck.txt"
$maintenanceKeyList = Get-Content "C:\\CrowdStrike-Master\\Maintenance_Key.txt"
$Credential = Get-Credential

$i = 0
foreach ($computer in $computerList) {
$maintenanceKey = $maintenanceKeyList\[$i\]
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -Credential $Credential -ScriptBlock {
#Stop-Process -Name CSFalconService -force

        & "C:\Temp-CrowdStrike\CsUninstallTool.exe" MAINTENANCE_TOKEN=$using:maintenanceKey /quiet   
    }
    $i++

}
```

Nothing is working. I tried different approach but maintenance management is key to uninstall CrowdStrike

Comment: Following https://stackoverflow.com/help, please describe what does happen. Please copy and paste any error messages as text (no pictures) into the question.